# Hide a database schema to a Login/User in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-schema

In a SQL Server database there are:

- 2 schemas: `dbo` and `customized_schema`
- 2 users: `sa` and `standard_user`

Under the schema `[customized_schema]` there are the entities with customized features of my standard application.

I want the deny the user `standard_user` to the schema customized_schema, but what I want is even hide the structure of the tables, views, code from functions and stored procedure.

I've tried this but does not work:

```
DENY UPDATE ON SCHEMA::[customized_schema] TO [standard_user]
GO
DENY TAKE OWNERSHIP ON SCHEMA::[customized_schema] TO [standard_user]
GO
DENY CONTROL ON SCHEMA::[customized_schema] TO [standard_user]
GO
DENY EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::[customized_schema] TO [standard_user]
GO
DENY DELETE ON SCHEMA::[customized_schema] TO [standard_user]
GO
DENY INSERT ON SCHEMA::[customized_schema] TO [standard_user]
GO
DENY ALTER ON SCHEMA::[customized_schema] TO [standard_user]
GO
DENY REFERENCES ON SCHEMA::[customized_schema] TO [standard_user]
GO
DENY SELECT ON SCHEMA::[customized_schema] TO [standard_user]
GO
DENY VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::[customized_schema] TO [standard_user]
GO
DENY VIEW CHANGE TRACKING ON SCHEMA::[customized_schema] TO [standard_user]
GO
```

I want to compare databases (with Visual Studio 2012 SSDT) and deploy changes use the `standard_user`, expecting to ignore the customer features.

Answer (score 0):

DbDefence can hide schema, table structures, etc.
As far as I know they use undocumented features of SQL Server. There is no way to do it in documented way.
DBDefence is free for databases less than 200 Mb